# On click of save button, 1 column to take the value of another column in a list

Tags: column

I have a list with columns "due date" and "revised date" in SharePoint.

I want to enter the due date column only when I am entering items for the first time. Onclick of save button I want the revised due date to have the value of due date. The revised due date can be editable later but for the first time it should take the value of due date.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to accomplish this:

You can use the server side object model by creating an event receiver that fires on the item added/adding event.  The following code will accomplish changing the field value:

```
var thisItem = properties.ListItem;
var date = DateTime.Parse(thisItem["DueDate"].toString());
thisItem["RevisedDueDate"] = date;
thisItem.Update();
```

You can use JavaScript to set the value of the revised due date within the `PreSaveFunction()`.  To do so, just modify the newform for the list, and add this to a content editor web part:

```
function PreSaveAction() {  
    var revised = $("input[title='Revised Due Date']");
    if(!revised.value())
        revised.value($("input[title='Due Date']").val());
    return true;
}
```

If either field is a required field, then append the title with: " Required Field" (note the space in front of Required Field).  So if Due Date was required, it you would use the following selector: `$("input[title='Due Date Required Field']")`

If you cannot use JavaScript or use Server Side code, then you can use a workflow that runs when an item is created to set the value of `Revised Due Date`.

Comment: I tried the javascript code but its disabling the save option of the form.i haven' t tried the server side object code.

Comment: Can I see the code you used?  And try `PreSaveItems()`.  I confuse the two all the time.

Comment: I was not adding the jquery reference  before.Now it is working.Thanks a lot.

Comment: if the revised due date field is empty then perform the above code .how to incorporate it in the above  code?

Comment: See revision to answer

Comment: If(value) means that it not empty.i want to check if the   revised due date is empty, then copy the value of due date to revised due date.how it can be done?       How empty condition is checked?

Comment: See revision to answer.